# How to run sonar analysis for a multi-module Maven project in Jenkins

Tags: java, maven, jenkins, sonarqube, sonarqube-scan

I am new to Jenkins. I have a Maven project where I have 2 modules. I have configured it in Jenkins using custom work-space. I have given maven goals such as "clean", "install". Build is working fine. I have downloaded sonar plugin and when I add "sonar analysis with maven" option in post build section, the build is success. But the analysis is happening for only the parent module and not for the sub modules.

Comment: What projects are displayed if you are on `Home` (e.g. http://sonarqube_host:9000/)?

Comment: @ SubOptimal Only the parent module is displayed.

Comment: Please have a look the the few points I mention as answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Find below some comments where you could start to investigate.

Based on your logs the modules also scanned

```
Scan personaltitania_releases sonar.branch
Scan titania_releases sonar.branch
```

But there are no files indexed

```
0 files indexed
```

Mabye having a look at the [Administration Guide](http://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SONARQUBE51/Administration+Guide) would reveal some other points.